# Spring Boot disable @JmsListener via external property

Tags: spring-boot

I have an app that has a method which uses `@JmsListener` to listen for incoming messages from a remote JMS broker (i.e. Apache ActiveMQ Artemis in this case). However, now I would like to disable this method (that uses `@JmsListener`), but not remove it, so that I could reuse functionality of this method in an environment without a broker and at the same that I could continue using this very same method in an environment where a broker is present.

Is it possible to achieve this? If yes, how?

Comment: You can always add a feature toggle for doing that and check it before doing anything with the message, your @JmsListener method will start with that if. The toggle could be stored in database for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out.

**step no.1** ***disable jms autostart***

I'm using the default jms listener container factory in my Spring Boot configuration

```
@Bean(name = "jmsListenerContainerFactory")
public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory() {
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory =
            new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    factory.setSessionTransacted(true);
    factory.setConnectionFactory(cachingConnectionFactory());
    return factory;
}
```

And so to disable it I needed to tinker a configuration to something like this

```
@Bean(name = "jmsListenerContainerFactory")
public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory(
        **@Value("${spring.jms.listener.auto-startup}") boolean autoStart**) {
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory =
            new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    factory.setSessionTransacted(true);
    factory.setConnectionFactory(cachingConnectionFactory());
    **factory.setAutoStartup(autoStart);**
    return factory;
}
```

**NOTE:** ** used for emphasis

**step no.2 *update application.properties/application.yml***

if yml format is used add this to **application.yml**

```
spring:
  jms:
    listener:
      auto-startup: true
```

if properties format is used add this to **application.properties**

```
spring.jms.listener.auto-startup=true
```

**step no.3 *run spring boot artifact***

if you want to disable jms then run your artifact as

```
java -jar myjarfile.jar --spring.jms.listener.auto-startup=false
```

and this should be enough to disable jms, if however you want to enable jms
then just execute your artifact as

```
java -jar myjarfile.jar
```

or

```
java -jar myjarfile.jar --spring.jms.listener.auto-startup=true *(redundant)*
```

**NOTE:** ** used for emphasis

Comment: Thank you @miroana for me only this change works in test application.yaml:

```
spring:
  jms:
    listener:
      auto-startup: true
```